# How to correctly standardize spatial data?

Tags: clustering, standardization, geostatistics

I have measurements of a set of socio-economic variables on italian municipalities; the aim is to run a series of clustering algorithms on them, in order to see if any significant pattern of local association emerge. I'd like your input on the correct way to standardize the variables, since most of my data is some sort of ratio.

If for example I have data on the density per square km, the mean density is obviously different from the value that I would get summing all residents of all municipalities and then dividing by the total area of the region, altought maybe not *that* different -- I haven't tried it yet. What would you think is the correct way to approach this problem?